# communication between RabbitMQ & IBMMQ

Tags: rabbitmq, ibm-mq

we have 2 Messaging Middlewares like RabbitMQ & IBMMQ and have clients on both the sides, Is there any way we can push messages from RabbitMQ so that clients that are connecting to IBMMQ can consume and vice versa, i mean if i send message to RabbitMQ that will land into IBMMQ broker ?

Comment: Yes, we do it all the time.  You create a "bridge" consumer on one bus that is itself a publisher to the other bus.  Depending on your exact requirements, this may require modifying the existing producers so that they can forward such messages as though they came from themselves.

Comment: do you have any link that i can refer with respect to RabbitMQ

Comment: Take a look at Apache Camel. It can route messages between both brokers.

Comment: @Nicholas That looks like an interesting piece of software - I't would be great if you could add an answer to this question with an example :)